# Value At Risk for Long and short position with same maturity and same traded price

Tags: value-at-risk

I am not a quant geek.I always have doubt  what should be the VaR output for portfolio contains long and short of the same maturity @ same traded price. e.g. CME corn future of sept expiry

## Groundwork

I was using the full revaluation with PnL approach at 95 percentile. The output was coming as zero.

Comment: Are both positions (long&short) for exactly the same instrument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your portfolio has both long and short position, it means it is completely hedge. Under such scenario, VaR would become zero, as there is no risk involve in portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

VaR is a method for simulating value of your future portfolio. If your portfolio is always zero, this is like not investing anything. Thus, there's no risk and VaR must always be zero.